# How do I find the content of a message that a user replied to in discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently developing a bot that pins messages in a text file to bypass the message pin limit in discord servers, and my system works by having a user reply to a message with -pin and it will save that message and the message author in a text file. The problem is that I don't know how to get the content of the replied to message and the author of said message. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if(command === 'pin'){
    message.channel.send('Ok, pinning that. Use -seepins to see all the pins.'),
    //i have no clue how to get the message that was replied to please help let pinned = 
    //im begging you please i have no idea let pinnedauthor = message.
    fs.writeFile('messages.txt', pinned + ' written by ' + pinnedauthor + '\n', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}
```

this is what I currently have. I just need to find out how to get the two things mentioned in the first paragraph and it should work.

Any help is appreciated, and thank you for reading this through.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the message object, you have a variable named reference. If your message is a reply reference should not be null and contains the ids of channelID, guildID, messageID.

With this you can then get the message content of the previous message with a line that looks like

client.on('message', async message => {
const repliedTo = await message.channel.messages.fetch(message.reference.messageID);

console.log(repliedTo.content);
});
Just be careful with the message.reference.messageID you have to add error handling to avoid crash when looking for an undefined variable.